# New, undocumented, data types in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, types

I am coming back to SQLite after an absence of many years.  My understanding of SQLite has always been that it has a rather simple set of data types - INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB & NULL and indeed [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) suggests exactly that.

However, I just looked at the [command line tutorial](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) on the SQLite site where it immediately starts talking about `varchar` `smallint` etc.  Is this merely the result of some sloppy documentation or does the current version of SQLite offer a mySQLesque cacophony of data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `smallint` and `varchar` types are listed on the SQLite data-types page:

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

- `smallint` is an `INTEGER`
- `varchar(n)` is `TEXT`

Comment: So given the "affinity" the only purpose served by using SMALLINT as opposed to INTEGER when creating a SQLite table would be to make a future transition to another database easier?

Comment: Yes, the automatic conversions determined by the affinity are intended to be compatible with the automatic conversions of other DBs.